# Symbol level drawing using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, symbology

Can ArcPy tick this automatically？

I have hundreds of .shp file which need to set the symbol-level-drawing and tick the option below. It's such a boring job.

[image]

Comment: ArcObjects certainly can, but not all of AO functionality was ported to ArcPy.

Comment: Maybe it is possible to duplicate the ticked layer, then change data source for each of your layers. I havent tried